# Consume fastest item from multiple observables

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I have multiple observables, that represent long task with single result.

```
Observable<String> longOp1 = getDataFromServer(server1);
Observable<String> longOp2 = getDataFromServer(server2);
Observable<String> longOp3 = getDataFromServer(server3);
```

How to run all tasks in parallel and consume only fastest result, also discard other observables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Observable<String> quickest = Observable.amb(longOp1, longOp2, longOp3);
```

Now, I program in c# using Rx.NET so I might have the syntax slightly wrong, but this should be pretty close.

The `.amb(...)` operator takes the first result and disposes of all of the source observables.